# Which Vaishnava theories are based on Gopâlatâpini Upanishad?

Tags: vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism

Swami Vivekananda makes a remark in one of his lectures that many Vaishnava theories have come from Gopala Tapini Upanishad.

Complete Works / Volume 3 / Lectures from Colombo to Almora / [The Religion we are born in](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_3/Lectures_from_Colombo_to_Almora/The_Religion_we_are_born_in):

> If any sect in India wants to have its ideas established with a firm hold on the people it must base them on the authority of the Vedanta. They all have to do it, whether they are Dvaitists or Advaitists. **Even the Vaishnavas have to go to Gopâlatâpini Upanishad to prove the truth of their own theories.**

There are a lot of Vaishnava scriptures which Vaishnavas refer frequently so which theories are unique to Gopalatapini Upanishad which are not found in other Vaishnava scriptures?

Answer (score 1):

In the Gopala-Tapani-Upanishad, we get Sri Krisshna as Para-Brahman.

> In this Sruti, two-handed Sri Krishna and His human leeleas are mentioned. He is the dearest to the Gopis. at the same time, He is Mayadisha, Rasika, Anandaghana-vigraha, and Brahman Himself.(Gaudiya Vaishnava Darshan, Radhagovinda Nath, Sadhana Prakashani, page 35)

So the **Vaishnava commentaries focusing on Sri Krishna as the Supreme Goal** like the Gaudiya Vaishnavas have used this as the most authentic source to present Sri Krishna as the Supreme God . The Vedas are the highest authority as per the Sanatana Dharma and they are Divine Wisdom. Mention of Sri Krishna and His leelas with full glory in the Upanishad makes Sri Krishna worshioable to all followers of the Sanatana Dharma.